# The newest version of Skype doesn't work. How do I get a previous version?

Tags: windows-xp, skype

A member of my family has a machine under Windows XP SP2. I tried to upgrade it to SP3 a few times in the past, but the upgrade failed. Moving to a newer OS is not an option either.

Recently, the person updated Skype to the newest version, and Skype is not working any longer, showing the following error:

> Failed to get proc address for GetLogicalProcessorInformation (KERNEL32.dll)

The error was already encountered by other Skype users and indicates that Skype tries to access a feature which was introduced in Windows XP SP3. Two solutions are suggested:

- [Upgrade to SP3](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12388/why-am-i-getting-a-fatal-error-kernel32-dll-when-i-try-to-launch-skype). Like I already explained, I can't do that.
- [Install the older Skype 6.6](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Failed-to-get-proc-address-for-GetLogicalProcessorInformation-on/td-p/1787546). The problem is, I can't find any trustful source where I can download it. Moreover, some sites like CNET pretend they have Skype 6.6, but actually download a different version (6.18, if I remember well), or lead to the latest version. The link to the official site provided in the linked answer is broken as well.

What are my options?

Comment: Even if you download 6 version [this](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Older-versions-of-Skype/m-p/3425413/highlight/true#M287867) message appear. Probably need [much older version](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/skype/). You better create question about how XP failed upgrade to SP3.

Comment: You might want to ask over on the [skype community](http://community.skype.com/?category.id=English). It may not even still be possible. Skype recently [retired](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/06/20/making-way-for-the-next-generation-of-skype-on-desktop/ ) most prior version to prepare for future architecture.

Comment: Considering that Windows XP is at this point 4 months past official End of Life and that Skype appears to be moving forward on the back end as well as the client, you may have to realize that an alternate solution for video conferencing may be needed. Various web based solutions, such as Google Hangouts or the wide assortment of WebRTC sites are available and should be an option.

Comment: Can I see your svcpack.log etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't [install SP3 on Windows XP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/learn-how-to-install-windows-xp-service-pack-3-sp3) 64-bit:

I had the same problem with Skype and [installing this version of Skype](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/skype-5-9-0-123) solved the issue.

Comment: A user (in a deleted answer) has indicated that many old skype installations can be packaged with addware/malware. I think it is important to realise that can exist, so I am providing that disclaimer/warning here so there are no surprises. Having a backup first , is always wise.